# Why is an article "un(e) / le / la" always omitted in the construction "Te voilà + noun"?

Tags: articles

> Te voilà **membre** à part entière de notre club.

This question has always been on my mind every time I use this sentence construction, but why the lack of "un"? Considering that "tu es ***un*** membre de notre club", the temptation is great to include "un".

> Te voilà **un membre** à part entière de notre club.

Comment: Both versions are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Tu es membre de notre association" is used to indicate that you have the statute of a member.
It is more idiomatic than "tu es un membre de notre association." 
because the article is only used if you want to precise 
what kind of member you are:
"Tu es un membre actif de notre association."
"Tu es un jeune membre de notre association."
"Tu es un membre blond de notre association."
"Tu es un membre récent de notre association."
Somehow, the accent is on the adjective ("actif", "jeune", etc.).

But if you want to precise the statute, the article comes back:
"Tu es membre honoraire de notre association."
"Tu es 'jeune membre' de notre association."
meaning that the association has some particular statute of "membre honoraire" or "jeune membre" for some of its members.

Answer (score 3):

You can very well say "Tu es membre de notre club."
As you can say for example "Te voilà le chef de la famille."

So I am not convinced that there is any difference in usage after "Te voila .." and "Tu es ..".

Answer (score 2):

"Membre" est utilisé comme adjectif qui définit son statut par rapport au club.